# Button does not animate

Tags: qt, animation, qtgui

I created a new QWidget with a single button in Qt Designer and i added this to the source code :

```
void MainWindow::startAnimation()
{
    QPropertyAnimation animation(ui->pushButton, "geometry");
    animation.setDuration(3000);
    animation.setStartValue(QRect(this->x(),this->y(),this->width(),this->height()));
    animation.setEndValue(QRect(this->x(),this->y(), 10,10));
    animation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutBounce);
    animation.start();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    startAnimation();
}
```

When I click on the button, it disappears and it doesn't animate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `animation` gets out of scope and is automatically deleted at the end of the `startAnimation()` function. That's why nothing happens. Create the `QPropertyAnimation` instance with `new` and delete it later using `finished` signal and `deleteLater` slot, like this:

```
void MainWindow::startAnimation()
{
    QPropertyAnimation* animation = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->pushButton, "geometry");
    ...
    connect(animation, SIGNAL(finished()), animation, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    animation->start();
}
```

Comment: You don't have to make a connection to delete the animation when it's finished. Just set the deletion policy to QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped when calling [start()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractanimation.html#start). `animation->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped)`